CI / CD Salesforce - Bitbucket ENVIRONMENT variables issues in pipelines
I am trying to setup it CI/CD for salesforce using bitbucket.
I have create a connected app for each environments (qa, uat, production)
And in bitbucket > repository settings > deployments:
I have added the sandboxes for staging environment and the production environment. For each environment I have set ENVIRONMENT variables:
USERNAME
CONSUMER_KEY
LOGIN_URL
ENVIRONMENT

Like this:

but when I push a commit to test the deployment, the ENVIRONMENT variable returns an error.

ENVIRONMENT variable is not set

I use echo in the script to be able to log the error
set -e
# echo is used to print the message on the console
echo "Starting the build process for environment: $ENVIRONMENT"

if [ -z "$ENVIRONMENT" ]; then
    echo "ENVIRONMENT variable is not set."
    exit 1
fi

Currently the build fails here when I have clearly created the ENVIRONMENT variable:

finally these are the deployment steps in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml:
# Production deployment
release/master:
  - step: *build-pipeline
  - step: *destructive-pre
  - step: *deploy-full-package
  - step: *deploy-env-spec-config
  - step: *destructive-post

Even trying to add deployment to the steps as shown below:
# Production deployment
release/master:
 deployment: production
 steps:
  - step: *build-pipeline
  - step: *destructive-pre
  - step: *deploy-full-package
  - step: *deploy-env-spec-config
  - step: *destructive-post

the environment variable is still null.
How can I fix the error with the ENVIRONMENT variable being null.
Thanks

You should split your question to focus on one issue at a time

In case someone is facing the same issue, I managed to solve my problem with the environment variables returning null.
You need to use stage in your pipeline and define the deployment on the stage level, like below:
pipelines:
  branches:
    release/master:
      - stage:
          name: Some name for this stage
          deployment: production
          steps:
            - step: *build-pipeline
            - step: *destructive-pre
            - step: *deploy-full-package
            - step: *deploy-env-spec-config
            - step: *destructive-post

